# Constructing safe SQL statement with multiple AND/OR conditons

Tags: python, sql

I have the following problem: I have a really large SQL statement inside Python code in string form:

```
sql = f"""
 *many statements here*
"""
```

Part of that SQL statement is:

```
where 1 = 1
     and selector in ('YES', 'NO')
     AND parameter1 = value1
     AND parameter2 = value2.1 OR parameter2 = value2.2
     AND ...
```

where those AND/OR statements are given by Python dictionary in the form

```
{ parameter1: [value1], parameter2: [value2.1, value 2.2], ...}
```

I've written a function which takes that dictionary and unfolds it to become a string in the form:

```
AND (parameter1 = value1) AND ((parameter2 = value2.1) OR (parameter2 = value2.2)) AND ...
```

and inserted that string into large SQL statement via this function:

```
where 1 = 1
         and selector in ('YES', 'NO')
         {form_sql_statement_from_dictionary(dictionary)}
```

but it seems that this approach is vulnerable for SQL-injection attacks. Now, the safe way would be to parametrise the large SQL statement, but since I don't know how many parameters and values there will be in dictionary, I don't know how to make such parametrisation. Also, I can't change the large SQL statement. Somehow I have to form and insert that AND/OR statement into existing string in safe way. Is there any way of doing that, rather than trying to police dictionary values itself?

Full Python script looks like this:

```
async def query_for_data(
    connection: "PgService", dictionary: Dict[str, Any]
) -> pd.DataFrame:
sql = f"""
*multiple SQL statements*
where 1 = 1
   and selector in ('YES', 'NO')
   {form_sql_statement_from_dictionary(dictionary)}
"""
data = await connection.fetch(sql)
data = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=[k for k in res[0].keys()])
return data
```

Function looks like this:

```
    def form_sql_statement_from_dictionary(
    dictionary: Dict[str, Any]) -> str:

    hashvalue = list(dictionary.values())
    scope = hashvalue[0]["scope"]

    dictionary_element_names = list(scope.keys())

    statement_elements = []
    for element_name in dictionary_element_names:
        dictionary_element_values = scope[element_name]

        if len(dictionary_element_values) == 1:
            dictionary_element_value = dictionary_element_values[0]
            statement_element = (
                f"( {prefix}{element_name} = '{dictionary_element_value}' )"
            )
            statement_elements.append(statement_element)
        else:
            statement_or_elements = []
            for dictionary_element_value in dictionary_element_values:
                statement_element = (
                    f"{prefix}{element_name} = '{dictionary_element_value}'"
                )
                statement_or_elements.append(statement_element)
            final_or_statement = "( " + " OR ".join(statement_or_elements) + ")"
            statement_elements.append(final_or_statement)

    final_statement = " AND " + " AND ".join(statement_elements)
    return final_statement
```

Comment: Show your current python script.  The basic approach is to build a list of parameters ***while*** you build the SQL string.  Then use something like `cursor.execute(sql_string, parameters)`.  That allows the literal values to be parameterised.  That presumes your dynamic column names are already safe; generated by you, not the user, such as chosen from a drop-down list of safe columns names that you generated, not the user.  But, without the python code and more details on where/how the dictionary is generated, we can't give you a specific answer, because you haven't asked a specific question.

Comment: I can't provide more details because I myself don't know where and how dictionary is generated, and this is not the point of the question. The point of question is how to make parametrisation with variable number of variables.

Comment: Then ***show your current python script***, and we can help you adapt it to use dynamic numbers of parameters.  As for your comment that `this is not the point of the question`, if you're not concerned with sql-injection attacks, please delete that part of your question.  If you ***are*** concerned with sql injection attacks, whether the column names can be trusted is extremely relevant.

Comment: I've added what I can add.

Comment: Please could you add an example dictionary.  For example, the example structure you gave has no element `"scope"`, and I'm answering this while at work so am not too inclined to reverse engineer the dictionary structure ;)

Comment: Where does `prefix` come from?

Answer (score 0):

Details found here:

- https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html

First, build the SQL where clause with positional arguments, such as...

```
(x.col1 = %s) AND (x.col2 = %s OR x.col3 = %s)
```

At the same time create a list of those parameters

```
['foo', 'foo', 'bar']
```

Then use a parameterised query...

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql, parameters)
data = await cursor.fetchall()
```

The parameterisation will quote and escape all the parameters for you, so no SQL Injection attacks from those.

***BUT*** the column names are still being substituted in to the query directly.  There is no inbuilt way to protect you from that.  If a user has direct control over those strings, they can still hack you that way.

As such it is ***vital*** that you police, validate, whatever, those column names yourself, through whatever means are appropriate to your use case.

All in all, the revised python would look something like...

```
def form_sql_statement_from_dictionary(dictionary):
    hashvalue = list(dictionary.values())
    scope = hashvalue[0]["scope"]
    dictionary_element_names = list(scope.keys())
    prefix='ummmmmmmmmm.'
    statement_elements = []
    statement_params   = []
    for element_name in dictionary_element_names:
        statement_elements.append(
            ' OR '.join(
                f"{prefix}{element_name} = %s"
                    for item in scope[element_name]
            )
        )
        statement_params += scope[element_name]
    return '(' + ') AND ('.join(statement_elements) + ')', statement_params


async def query_for_data(
    connection: "PgService", dictionary: Dict[str, Any]
) -> pd.DataFrame:
    sql_where_clause, sql_params = form_sql_statement_from_dictionary(dictionary)
    sql = f"""
    *multiple SQL statements*
    where 1 = 1
       and selector in ('YES', 'NO')
       and {sql_where_clause}
    """
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql, sql_params)
    res = await cursor.fetchall()
    data = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=[k for k in res[0].keys()])
    return data
```